# Java - Detecting the main monitor

Tags: java, multiple-monitors

I'd like to know if it's possible to detect the main monitor of a computer in Java, and if so I'd like to know how to(I.e. code example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an JFrame running, the following will give you the list of devices:

```
GraphicsEnvironment gEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] dDevices= gEnvironment.getScreenDevices();
```

Not sure, but the first one should be the default one.

You can also try:

```
GraphicsEnvironment gEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice dDevice= gEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice();
```

Which returns the default screen device.

Comment: see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getDefaultScreenDevice%28%29